# Does it optimize memory to eager load a child object when you only need to use 1 of its attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, memory, activerecord, eager-loading

An `Order` has many child `Items`. `Items` has many child `Charges`. In a `def display` type Controller method and its associated view, I'm looking to display: 1) ALL attributes of an `order` and its child `items` and 2) the sum of the `amount` attribute from `Charges` in various user-friendly combinations. E.g.,

```
<%= @order.id %>
<%= @order.name %>

<% @order.items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.id %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% end %>

@total_item_charges

# below 2 should sum into @total_item_charges above
@total_item_type_a_charges
@total_item_type_b_charges
```

Because I need all of `items` attributes later, I think I know to eager load that, but given I only really need 1 attribute of `charges` (and 1 to query), should I eager load that as well?

**Approach A**

Use `includes` to eager load the child `items` as well as the grandchildren `charges`, so that all the info is loaded once and used as needed

```
# CONTROLLER
@order = Order.includes(items: [:charges]).where(id: params[:order_id]).first

# items/charges already loaded into memory
@order.items.each do |i|
  i.charges.each do |c|
    if c.type == "type_a"
      @total_item_type_a_charges += c.amount
    else
      @total_item_type_b_charges += c.amount
    end
  end
end

@total_item_charges = @total_item_type_a_charges + @total_item_type_b_charges
```

**Approach B**

Still eager load child `items`, but not the grandchildren `charges`, instead do `where` queries when needed

```
# CONTROLLER
@order = Order.includes(:items).includes(:shipments).where(id: params[:order_id]).first

@order.items.each do |i|
  @total_item_type_a_charges += i.charges.where(type:"type_a").pluck(:amount).inject(:+)
  @total_item_type_b_charges += i.charges.where(type:"type_b").pluck(:amount).inject(:+)
end

@total_item_charges = @total_item_type_a_charges + @total_item_type_b_charges
```

In your answer...

1. Totally flag if I'm using `includes` entirely wrong for everything (gulp, hope that's not the case)
2. If there are trade-offs between memory-usage and speed (i.e., one approach is faster but uses more memory, while another is slower but uses less, please help me flag as this will help)
3. It's OK if the answer is that either is fine, or that it depends on nuanced situations, I am asking because I'm wondering if there are rules of thumb here
4. Would love to know how to test this in the console?? I can see milliseconds to load each query, but not memory usage

Answer (score 0):

You would have to consider a real world situation and, ideally, do some performance testing. If I was to implement this I would add a `total_charge` field to `Item` and keep that updated whenever a charge is added, updated or removed, similar to `belongs_to ... counter_cache: true`.

An alternative might be something like the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items # as before
  has_many :items_with_charge, :class_name: 'Item', 
           -> { joins(:charges).group('items.id').select('items.*, sum(charges.amount) as total_amount)') }
  ...
end
```

Now if you do something like:

```
order = Order.includes(:items_with_charge)
```

Each item should include the total which can be accesses using `item['total_amount']`